# how to convert a specific/current date to unix timestamps or epoch timestamps in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, time

i am a newcomer in javascript and have a question regarding unix timestamps in javascript.

suppose the date is "2009/11/23" or "1890-03-12" or "1890-03-12 12:23:00" or current date through "new Date()".

How to convert these dates to unix timestamps or epoch timestamps with detailed explanation ?

I am confused and have no idea about how to convert it into epoch timestamps in javascript ?

Comment: Parse the string to its components for year, month and day then use the Date constructor and *getTime* method: `new Date(year, month - 1, day).getTime()`. That will be milliseconds, divide by 1,000 to get seconds. Note months are zero indexed so subtract 1 from the calendar month number. Don't use the built–in parser.

Answer (score 0):

for  unix timestamp

```
 new Date('2020.08.24').getTime() / 1000
```

For more information go through Documentation

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: this should be the accepted answer, mostly because it's correct, but also because it's the simplest way to get the job done, which is quite important for a new user.

Comment: Thanks @daf !! ..for accepting answer.

Comment: @harshadkapei but when i checked your answer in browser console but with different date formats such as "new Date('2020/08/24').getTime() / 1000" or "new Date('2020-08-24').getTime() / 1000" i get a different answer. which one i shall consider correct. Please suggest.

Comment: Looks like the second one is including the timezone offset in the answer, which is probably why RobG warned about it. So here's the big hitter: if you're not just don't this for learning, check out a library like moment or luxon. If you're just learning at this stage, you've learned an important lesson early on: JavaScript dates suck.

Comment: I have compared '2020.08.24' format date value to  '2020/08/24'  and  '2020-08-24' format date respectively in browser and got  '2020/08/24' this format value same . So I suggested you to go througth '2020/08/24' this format date.

Comment: Using the built–in parser is a bad idea, `new Date('2020.08.24')` produces an invalid date in at least one current implementation as does `new Date('1890-03-12 12:23:00')`. See [*MDN: Date.parse*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse).

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for Date.parse (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) which parses a date string to return an epoch timestamp.

Comment: Just posting a reference to another site is not an answer, it might be a helpful comment. Using the built–in parser is not encouraged.

Comment: it's the simplest answer for a person new to JavaScript. Introducing something heavy like Moment or Lumen is crazy when someone is just trying to learn. In addition, copy-pasting MDN documentation wouldn't have been any clearer.